# launch element of web page full screen in iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, html, mobile, safari

I'm hoping it's possible to be able to launch a div full screen within Safari on iOS. I'm using the jquery plugin Screenfull to achieve this on the desktop, and it works fine - but on iOS it has no effect. From what I can gather, the webkit display full screen properties are only available on the HTMLVideoElement DOM object. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: I guess you answered your own question.

Comment: I guess...probably an overlay lightbox or something is only option, with 100% width and height.